# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installation script: .bashrc, or .bash_profile?

Tags: bash

I'm following a manual installation procedure for an O'Reilly book on Data Science. The procedure details the environment variables required by Hadoop, Spark, pyMongo, and more.

The original script exports environmental variables to ~/.bash_profile, eg

```
export HADOOP_HOME=$PROJECT_HOME/hadoop
echo 'export HADOOP_HOME=$PROJECT_HOME/hadoop' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

etc.

I noticed that adding this code to ~/.bash_profile, then running

```
reload
```

at the command line apparently doesn't pick up the new vars.

A similar edit on ~/.bashrc, then

```
source .bashrc
```

seems to do the trick.

Before I convert this long installation script - what will break if I do a wholesale replacement? (I know this is a common question, but the answers I've seen thus far aren't concise.)

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: There's no `reload` command in `bash`. Is that one of your aliases?

Comment: @BrianPiercy It is, but this question isn't about programming in bash, it's about how to use it as an interactive shell, and how to configure your login settings.

Comment: `.bash_profile` is only executed in your login shell. `.bashrc` is executed in every interactive shell. Environment variables normally only need to be set once when you login, they're inherited automatically by all the other shells.

Comment: You can use `source .bash_profile` to pick up changes to that script.

Comment: ok, thanks @Barmar. i'll proceed with .bashrc.